# Does spring internally uses servlets?

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I have a doubt whether the servlets internally uses servlets or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is. Spring-MVC uses [`DispatcherServlet`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) under the hood.

> Central dispatcher for HTTP request handlers/controllers, e.g. for web UI controllers or HTTP-based remote service exporters. Dispatches to registered handlers for processing a web request, providing convenient mapping and exception handling facilities.
>
> This servlet is very flexible: It can be used with just about any workflow, with the installation of the appropriate adapter classes...